# I can't add Service reference in VS 2019

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, service-reference

'https://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/service/kpspublic.asmx?WSDL'

I want to do a request on this service.

But when I add the service reference, the connected service doesn't appear either.

**Services seem to be attached in csproj but I can't use it, how can I use it?**

I am using web service for the first time

Comment: If its a public service could you please shere the service interface so that can reproduce the issue? Screenshot really doesn't helpful here to contribute on your problem.

Comment: okay i got it. I haven't been able to progress yet, anyone have any ideas? I want to make a request to a web service in .net core, but I can't add it to the service reference. I can't access its class.

Comment: Could you please share your service interface which you are trying to integrate?